# Reverting Arduino Environment on OS X

Tags: arduino-ide

I am using Arduino environment 1.6.17 on OS X, 10.12.2. In this version, all of the core avr library stuff is located in ~/Library/Arduino15.

I was told by a vendor that in order for their program to compile properly, I needed to compile it under 1.6.4 of the Arduino environment. I dowloaded that version and compiled the program again. I could tell though, by the compiler messages, that while the IDE may be version 1.6.4, the program was still compiling with version 1.6.17 tools and avr libraries. Is there anyway to change that so I can get it to actually compile with all tools and libs from 1.6.4?

Comment: Send the product back for a refund if the vendor isn't going to provide proper support. Arduino IDE 1.6.4 is outdated and it would take very little effort for the vendor to make it compatible with current versions.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try the total removal of the environment and then a re-installation as JRobert suggested, because I didn't really want to nuke my current environment. But his post did inspire me to try and run the 1.6.4 environment from another user account that had never run any Arduino stuff before. This seemed functionally equivalent to his or her suggestion. That seemed to work. Although, I still have a feeling that there is a more convenient solution out there.

Comment: You can be selective about the files you allow an app remover to delete. If you've modified your Preferences.txt, for example, don't delete it, and/or pull a copy of it aside somewhere for safety. But you're on the right track - something isn't being down-graded that needs to be, when you install the older version.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the Arduino app with [AppCleaner](http://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) or a similar application remover. AppCleaner should find any related files not contained within the app. Let it remove them. Then reinstall Arduino 1.6.4.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a recent-ish version of the Arduino IDE, it installs stuff in `~/Library/Arduino15`, unless it already exists. So when you installed 1.6.4, it saw the `~/Library/Arduino15` folder and proceeded without installing its own version of the tools.

The only way to have your 1.6.4 running alongside a newer version is to have copies of the `~/Library/Arduino15` folder, by renaming them when appropriate.